# add-apt-repository looks for 'jessy' instead of 'trusty' version of the source

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to install ffmpeg 3 in my docker container via add-apt-repository and the source I use is [this](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/). I have used ubuntu:trusty in my docker container, nevertheless, when I try to `apt-get update`, the fetched source is not trusty but jessie, which does not exist:

> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found.

Here is the log of my build:

```
 ---> Running in 7db074d1f86f
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [599 kB]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.1 kB]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]
Fetched 9686 kB in 14s (676 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
FROM node
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build
ENV NODE_ENV production
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Comment: Not a programming question; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe ask at [ubuntu.se] instead, but they (too) will want to see your full `sources.list` and `sources.list.d` to figure out where the Debian entries come from.

Comment: I recommend that you review the [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) from docker, specifically on the Dockerfile `RUN` section. You have some `apt-get` lines that could break without warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
FROM node
RUN ...
```

Your commands are not running on a "ubuntu:trusty" image, they are being run on a "node:latest" image. You created a multi-stage build with no commands in the first stage, just a large image download.

The "node:latest" image you are using is based on "buildpack-deps:jessie" [as seen in thier Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a7e88f1dd2102689180f485c51133212f45fa064/Dockerfile.template). And if you follow that back enough, you'll find "debian:jessie" in a [parent Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/d662dc69f910feb241f6d0c9d2cd6cc2fb6c5e6c/jessie/curl/Dockerfile).

You need to either change your base image or your repository you are adding so that they match.

Comment: I am just learning Docker, so I missed the fact that you have pointed out. Thank you very much, I will go over best practices as you recommend!